# solr core reload without an tomcat restart

Tags: debian, tomcat, solr

I want to really often the synonyms_*.txt in the solr server. I have 2 cores. One for the production System and one the staging. I copy with incron and scp the new generated synonymes to the solr server and restart the tomcat to reload it.

But it can be broken if any config is crap or any product is actually in the update process. Give it any solution to restart/reload one core only via cli?

Thanks for your help.

Dennis

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "cores"?  Do you mean it's two independent copies of the solr webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reload a core via the API

Have a look: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD

use wget to call a reload on your core

Comment: I have written an small shell script for this:

https://github.com/denniswisnia/solr-tools