# How do I add a Solr core without restarting the Solr server?

Tags: solr

#### Question

How do I add a Solr core without restarting the Solr server?

Is it possible at all?

#### My current way of adding Solr cores (*with* server restart)

According to [this FAQ](https://www.codeenigma.com/host/faq/how-do-i-create-solr-core-my-server) I do the following:

1. Copy an existing Solr core
2. Rename the core name by opening the file `core.properties` and editing the field `name` like `name=my_core`
3. Restart the Solr Windows service

#### My preferred way of adding Solr cores (*without* server restart)

Same as above but after step 2 I'd like to have some way to make the core visible in the Solr web interface without having to restart the entire server.

#### My research so far

Resources on the Internet indicate that it should be possible, but I havent been able to get it to work yet.

**Forum: Load cores without restarting/reloading Solr**

In [this forum](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Load-cores-without-restarting-reloading-Solr-td980773.html) they just say "yes, it is possible" and point to this [Solr documentation page called CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin).

**Serverfault question: solr core reload without an tomcat restart**

This serverfault question [solr core reload without an tomcat restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/355766/solr-core-reload-without-an-tomcat-restart) has [an answer](https://serverfault.com/a/393645/127762) which points to [#RELOAD section](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD) of the same CoreAdmin Solr documentation as above, but I can't get Solr to load new cores with neither

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=my_core
```

nor

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD
```

For `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=my_core` I get an HTTP 400 Bad Request.

For `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD` I get the following NullPointerException which I don't know how to interpret:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">500</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="error">
        <str name="trace">
            java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:342) at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:227) at java.util.TreeSet.contains(TreeSet.java:234) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleReloadAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:726) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:226) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:189) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:783) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:282) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:220) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        </str>
        <int name="code">500</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

#### Versions

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- Solr 5.1.0

Comment: Why RELOAD? Shouldn't you rather invoke CREATE to add a new core?

Comment: @Oliver: Because I already copied and pasted an existing core, I don't need to CREATE the core anymore (see section *My current way of adding Solr cores*). Therefore, I just want the new core to show up and assumed a RELOAD would suffice even if it isn't a RELOAD, but only a LOAD to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy an existing Solr core
2. Rename the core name by opening the file core.properties and editing the field name like name=my_core
3. <s>Restart the Solr Windows service</s>
4. On the Solr web interface, select `Core Admin` and click on button `Add Core`
5. Type

   name = `my_core`

   instanceDir: `my_core`
6. Click button `Add Core`

[image: Solr Core Admin Add Core]

Comment: And if you want to know what query this did, so you can do it yourself, you can watch the network tab of your browser's developer tools. You'll see it go by as an AJAX request.

Comment: @Lernkurve, I don't have any existing core on my fresh Solr 7.0.1 installation. What do I need to do?